# How to get remote IP address over a ssh remote port forwarding tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I'm running a test server behind NAT. I've forwarded remote port `2222` from another public IP server (`example.com`) to port `22` of the server behind NAT (`localhost`) as follows.

```
autossh -f -N -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 2222:localhost:22 root@example.com
```

Now the local `ssh` server behind NAT getting only `::1` as IP address of all clients irrespective of client's actual IP address.

Output from `w` in `localhost` is like this.

```
 22:27:37 up  8:03,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.03, 0.09
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user tty7     :0               14:24    8:03m  1.27s  0.33s /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE
user pts/0    ::1              22:27    1.00s  0.34s  0.03s w
```

`/var/log/auth.log` in `localhost` has entry like this

```
Feb 28 22:27:32 localhost sshd[5201]: Accepted password for user from ::1 port 55168 ssh2
```

Now I want to run `fail2ban` or `csf` firewall to block spam IP addresses. So, I want client's actual IP address. How can I do this? Is any `iptables` `NAT` rewriting rule helpful?

Comment: You cannot use failtoban to block IPs and you only see the IP address of the other side of the SSH tunnel...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, that's true. I'm asking is there a way to get the client's actual IP instead the IP address of other side of the tunnel's localhost ip `::1`?

Comment: I prefer going in via a VPN and not expose `ssh` ports to the Internet.

Comment: Maybe running a tun device and using iptables would be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The [SSH protocol messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-7.2) for opening a TCP forwarding session include the IP address and port of the client which connected to the forwarded port. The OpenSSH `ssh` utility just logs the information and doesn't do anything else with it:

```
$ ssh -v -R 2048:localhost:22 localhost
...
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 2048, originator ::1 port 49341
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To do something useful with the information, you'd have to do one of the following:

- Run `ssh` in debug mode and capture and parse the relevant debug output.
- [Modify](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) the `ssh` utility to log the information or otherwise do what you need it to do with the information.
- Use a different ssh client, or write your own. SSH libraries exist for most modern programming languages.

Comment: Sounds cumbersome....